# Foursquare API Venues.search() "categoryId" parameter issue with "near" param vs "ll" param

Tags: foursquare

With Foursquare's API Endpoint `Venues.search`:

If the `categoryId` parameter is coupled with the `ll` parameter, it returns the expected response; filtered venues by category.

However, if I use `categoryId` parameter with the `near` parameter, the response does not have the venues filtered.

Sample:

[Request with `ll`](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?limit=50&ll=34.1449,-118.1485713&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d129951735,4bf58dd8d48988d12d951735,4bf58dd8d48988d130951735,4bf58dd8d48988d17b941735,4bf58dd8d48988d17c941735,4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735,4bf58dd8d48988d181941735,4bf58dd8d48988d182941735,4bf58dd8d48988d18e941735,4bf58dd8d48988d193941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e1931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e2931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e3931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e4931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e5931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ef931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ef941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f1931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f2931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f6931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fc931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fd931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fe931735,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4e4c9077bd41f78e849722f9,4eb1bc533b7b2c5b1d4306cb,4f04b25d2fb6e1c99f3db0c0,4fceea171983d5d06c3e9823,5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c&radius=150&intent=checkin&oauth_token=YEUBXINMZIZEO0GE5XRBS2SLPVJPACS1DUZJZT1IYUGPVME5&v=20130325)returns filtered venues by categoryId.

[Request with `near`](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?limit=50&near=Los%20Angeles,%20CA&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d129951735,4bf58dd8d48988d12d951735,4bf58dd8d48988d130951735,4bf58dd8d48988d17b941735,4bf58dd8d48988d17c941735,4bf58dd8d48988d17f941735,4bf58dd8d48988d181941735,4bf58dd8d48988d182941735,4bf58dd8d48988d18e941735,4bf58dd8d48988d193941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e1931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e2931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e3931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e4931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1e5931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ef931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1ef941735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f1931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f2931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1f6931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fa931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fc931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fd931735,4bf58dd8d48988d1fe931735,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4e4c9077bd41f78e849722f9,4eb1bc533b7b2c5b1d4306cb,4f04b25d2fb6e1c99f3db0c0,4fceea171983d5d06c3e9823,5032792091d4c4b30a586d5c&intent=checkin&oauth_token=YEUBXINMZIZEO0GE5XRBS2SLPVJPACS1DUZJZT1IYUGPVME5&v=20130325) returns non-filtered venues by categoryId.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is secondary category matching. The results look like they're not filtered correctly because the response from search only shows the primary category. The venues actually match on a secondary category, which you can see by looking at the [venue detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) response.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. We'll start submitting invalid categories.